# Why is the lifetime of an object on the free store bound to scope?

Tags: c++

If I have some object pointing to `NULL` and i want to assign it using `new` in the scope of a function, why is the lifetime of this object limited to the scope?

```
SomeObject *o = nullptr;

void f(SomeObject *o)
{
    o = new SomeObject; //Not null
}

o->doWhatever(); //Null again
```

And: how can i assign `someObject` else then (without returning)?

Comment: Ages-old question -- you passed `o` by value into the function, so the original `o` is unaffected.

Answer (score 0):

The input argument that you are passing to function `f` has the same name as the global variable.

So the assignment inside function `f` applies for the local variable instead of the global variable.

Comment: I don't think `o` is in global scope. No more than  the executable statement `o->doWhatever();` is.

Comment: @StoryTeller: I see a global declaration `SomeObject *o = nullptr;` in the code.

Comment: And I see it followed by a global executable statement. So either the code is ill-formed, or those aren't really globals.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Yep, I understand your point. I've taken it for granted that the "global statement" was just "cut off" from some function, since the code wouldn't even compile otherwise (in opposed to the global declaration). But you are right that the code in its present state is ill-formed.